# Mouse drag event not being fired on 10.5

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a library which creates a window. I intercept mouse events in the view added to the window. It works fine on 10.6 and 10.7.

But on 10.5 "mouseDragged" call back is never called. Does anybody has any idea on how to fix it?

Regards,

Vishvesh

Answer (score 0):

Theres a setter on `NSWindow` to allow it to hear mouseMoved events which is

`-(void)setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:(BOOL)val;`

As to why its not working in 10.5 only I don't know but as a guess they are fairly expensive tracking wise so might be off by default in that version.

Comment: -(void)setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:(BOOL)val; is called. I get most of  the events but mousedrag is never called.